# 400 Bad Request when making POST request using curl_cffi

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the `curl_cffi` library in Python to make a POST request to the URL https://www.midjourney.com/api/auth/signin/discord. However, I am encountering a "400 Bad Request" error. I have received a successful response (status code 200) when retrieving the CSRF token from https://www.midjourney.com/api/auth/csrf, but when I attempt to make the POST request to https://www.midjourney.com/api/auth/signin/discord, I receive a "400 Bad Request" error.

The response text is an HTML page with the error details. I suspect that there might be some specific formatting requirements or additional parameters that need to be included in the request to https://www.midjourney.com/api/auth/signin/discord in order to avoid this error. Pasting all the other headers from the Browser Request did not help.

This is the code I am using:

```py
from curl_cffi import requests
import json, urllib

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get('https://www.midjourney.com/api/auth/csrf', impersonate="chrome110")
print(r.status_code)
csrf = json.loads(r.text)['csrfToken']

data = { "callbackUrl":"https://www.midjourney.com/app/", "csrfToken":csrf, "json":True}
headers = {
    'Content-length': str(len(urllib.parse.urlencode(data, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote))),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
h = requests.Headers([("content-length", str(len(urllib.parse.urlencode(data, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)))), ('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')])
r = s.post(f'https://www.midjourney.com/api/auth/signin/discord?', headers=h, allow_redirects=True, data=data, impersonate="chrome110")
print(r.status_code)
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```

I want too login to midjourney website with my script to retrive image data. But after the switch from requests to curl_cffi because off cloudflare anti bot protection i get the 400 Response

Answer (score 0):

In the previous versions, `curl_cffi` does switch from POST to GET as expected by most users. The latest version should have it fixed.